# Let $V$ be a vector space and $W_1, W_2$ be subspaces of $V.$ Show that $W_1/W_1\cap W_2\cong (W_1+W_2)/W_2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $W_1, W_2$ be two subspaces of $V.$ Show that $W_1/W_1\cap W_2\cong (W_1+W_2)/W_2.$ Hence conclude that, $\dim (W_1+W_2) = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 -\dim (W_1\cap W_2),$ if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are finite dimensional subspaces of $V.$

I tried finding an isomorphism from the quotient space of $W_1$ modulo $W_1\cap W_2$ i.e $W_1/W_1\cap W_2$ to the quotient space of $W_1+W_2$ modulo $W_2$ which is precisely, $ (W_1+W_2)/W_2.$

My solution goes like this:

We  know that, $$W_1/(W_1\cap W_2)=\{x+W_1\cap W_2:x\in W_1\}$$ and $$(W_1+W_2)/W_2=\{x+W_2:x\in W_1+W_2\}.$$

Now, let $x+W_2\in W_1+W_2/W_2,$ where $x\in W_1+W_2.$ So, $\exists w_1\in W_1$ and $w_2\in W_2$ such that $x=w_1+w_2$ and this means, $x+W_2=(w_1+w_2)+W_2=w_1+W_2\subseteq W_1/W_2.$

Again, if $x\in W_1/W_2$ then, $\exists w_1\in W_1$ such that $$x=w_1+W_2=w_1+(w_2+W_2)=(w_1+w_2)+W_2\subseteq (W_1+W_2)/W_2,$$ where, $w_2\in W_2.$

Thus, we can conclude, $$(W_1+W_2)/W_2=W_1/W_2.$$

Let $T:$$W_1/(W_1\cap W_2)$$\to (W_1+W_2)/W_2=W_1/W_2$ such that $T(w_1+(W_1\cap W_2))=w_1+W_2,\forall w_1\in W_1.$

Let $A=W_1\cap W_2.$

We note that, $T$ is indeed a linear transformation for if, $x+A,y+A\in W_1/(W_1\cap W_2)$ and $c\in F$ then, $T(c(x+A)+y+A)=T(cx+A+y+A)=cx+y+W_2=c(x+W_2)+(y+W_2)=cT(x+A)+T(y+A).$

We also, claim that $T$ is onto for if $w_1+W_2\in W_1/W_2$ then, $\exists w_1+A\in W_1/(W_1\cap W_2)$ such that, $T(w_1+A)=w_1+W_2.$

We observe that, $T$ is further, one-to-one, as if say,  $x+A\in N(T)$ then $T(x+A)=x+W_2=W_2\implies x\in W_2$ but $$x\in W_1\implies x\in W_1\cap W_2.$$ Therefore, $N(T)=W_1\cap W_2$ as $W_1\cap W_2$ is the zero vector of $W_1/(W_1\cap W_2).$

This proves that, $W_1/W_1\cap W_2\cong (W_1+W_2)/W_2.$

We know that,

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $W$ is a subspace of $V$ then, $\dim V/W=\dim V-\dim W.$

If, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are finite dimensional, then, $$\dim W_1/W_1\cap W_2=\dim (W_1+W_2)/W_2\implies \dim W_1-\dim W_1\cap W_2=\dim (W_1+W_2)-\dim W_2\implies\dim (W_1+W_2) = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 -\dim (W_1\cap W_2).$$

---

I want to know how I can improve the readability of the proof. Can the proof-writing be improved further? Any suggestions on how to improve the proof will be greatly appreciated. Lastly, if my solution contains any errors please feel free to point them out.